# Table row data-link onclick not getting fired after responding to format.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an index page that contains an HTML table where each row represents a record. I have used data-link and jquery to go to the show page of a record. The page also has a filter form. When filtering the table the controller responds with format.js and the data-link click isn't fired. The data-link click works fine on first visit and on reloading the page.

**application.js**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("link");
  })
})
```

**index.html.haml**

```
#companies_table
  = render 'business/companies/partials/companies_table'
= render 'business/companies/partials/filter'
```

**_companies_table.html.haml**

```
......    
%tbody
  - @companies.each do |company|
    %tr.cursor__pointer{"data-link": business_company_path(company)}
      %td
        = company.name
```

**_filter.html.haml**

```
= form_tag(business_companies_path, method: :get, remote: true) do
  .form-group
    %label
      = t(:search_by_name)
    = text_field_tag :search, nil, class: 'form-control', onkeyup: 'submitFilterForms();', autofocus: true, value: params[:search], onfocus: 'this.value = this.value;'
```

**index.js.haml**

```
$("#companies_table").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'business/companies/partials/companies_table')}");
```

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @companies = Company.filter(params.slice(:company_type, :search, :country)).decorate
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing your `trs` with your `format.js`.

But you attach the event handlers directly on the `tr`, so when you put new `tr` into the `dom`, they don't have an event handler attached.

So you have to use event delegation like this, you put your event handler on a parent object (for example `body` or some `div` around the table), that is not changed by the `format.js` like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "tr[data-link]", function() {
     window.location = $(this).data("link");
});
```

see: https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/#binding-events-to-elements-that-don-39-t-exist-yet

Another (less elegant) way, would attach the event handler in your `format.js`, but this is worse because you repeat yourself.

**index.js.haml**

```
$("#companies_table").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'business/companies/partials/companies_table')}");
$("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("link");
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm :-)